# how to hide systems status bar and show alert in status bar for few sec by animation in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

I want to show alert in status bar for small duration with animation and hide systems status bar for that duration

I have referred [this](https://github.com/jaydee3/JDStatusBarNotification) but enable to hide system's status bar for that particular time,failed to add animation

**Here is my code**

```
NSString *status=@"welcome..";
UIView *notificationView= [JDStatusBarNotification showWithStatus:(NSString *)status  styleName:JDStatusBarStyleDark];
CGRect statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
notificationView.frame=statusBarFrame;
[self.view addSubview:notificationView];
UIView *dismissNotificationView=[JDStatusBarNotification showWithStatus:(NSString *)status
dismissAfter:(NSTimeInterval)5.0f styleName:JDStatusBarStyleDark];
[self.view addSubview:dismissNotificationView];  `
```

also tried [this](https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay) but it moves another window then shows and turns back

here is the code used

```
 MTStatusBarOverlay *overlay = [MTStatusBarOverlay sharedInstance];
overlay.animation = MTStatusBarOverlayAnimationFallDown;  // MTStatusBarOverlayAnimationShrink
overlay.detailViewMode = MTDetailViewModeHistory;         // enable automatic history-tracking and show in detail-view
overlay.delegate = self;
overlay.progress = 0.0;
[overlay postImmediateFinishMessage:@"welcome" duration:2.0 animated:YES];
overlay.progress = 1.0;
```

please help..thanks in advance

Comment: So what do you want, want to hide the status bar completely for the whole App ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when you want the alert to appear, so I will assume just after loading the view. I didn't use the two frameworks, but tested it with a generic red UIView and it worked with the code below:

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController () {
        BOOL animating;
        CGRect aimFrame;
    }

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        animating = YES; //To set if we are showing the alert or not
        aimFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];

       [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];

        UIView *notificationView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [notificationView setFrame:aimFrame];
        [notificationView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        [self.view addSubview:notificationView];

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [notificationView removeFromSuperview];
            animating = NO;
            [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
        });
    }


    - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
        // Toggle based upon if we are showing the alert
        if (animating) {
            return YES;
        } else {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    @end
```

I hope this helps, let me know if it still doesn't work or if I miss understood something :)

Comment: should i put my code in [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]; method?

Comment: No, the method call tells the viewcontroller to recheck the statusbar appearance settings. So by calling it the view controller will check the function '(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden' and change the statusbar appearance accordingly. So with that we toggle between the system statusbar being shown and hidden (based upon what we have set animating to). Just change the above code so that the notification view is what you want. Does that make sense?

Comment: internet status...appeared and lost in whole application

Comment: So just place that in the `UIView *notificationView`. To have it pop up at different times, when you check, change animating to YES, then call  setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate to hide the system status bar. After that show the specific notification view. Then change animating to NO, and call  setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate again to show the status bar again. Does that make sense?

Comment: If the answer works, and actually answered your question, would you be so kind to mark it as answered, so others who might read this know it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Try my code to complete hide the status bar:

```
 -(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
           return YES;
    }
```